# How many ceritificates I will need if I use subdomains

Tags: ssl, certificate, subdomain, ssl-certificate

I have domain mydomain.com. I need use subdomains such test1.mydomain.com, helloworld.mydomain.com. These subdomains just host names in IIS bindings for my main site. Users of my sites can add subdomains. Is it possible to use one certificate for all subdomains and main domain? How can I test it with self signed sertificate?

Thanks!

Comment: Please also check http://www.startssl.com/?app=40 - they are offering the cheapest Wildcard-Certificates as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a wild-card certificate eg

http://www.rapidssl.com/buy-ssl/wildcard-ssl-certificate/index.html

Once all the domains are in effect alliasses of the main domain there should be no problem here.

I dont know much about self signing certificates - except that they seem to be more trouble than they are worth. for less than $10 you can get a cert (not wildcard) from someone like CheapSSLs and test with this if you want - it will just throw an error about the name of the domain not matching the certificate

Answer (score 3):

Typically a standard SSL Certificate is issued to a single Fully Qualified Domain Name only, which means it can be used only to secure the exact domain to which it has been issued. With the Wildcard SSL option activated you expand what's possible by receiving an SSL Certificate issued to *.domain.com. So if you apply for "*.mydomain.com" it will secure "anything.mydomain.com"

Not quite sure on how to do it with self-signed certificates. Hope this info helps.